# ERROR: WSDL - SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

Tags: php, security, soap, wsdl

I have a php code that uses soap

I get the error

> ERROR: WSDL - SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

It's a security wsdl so I need to send also username and password.
what is wrong in my code?
I see it at web and does'nt work from soap in php code.
here is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); 
$soap_url = 'http://some-ip/prod/app/soap/user/storeitemws?WSDL';
$sh_param = array(
                'username' => 'aya',
                'password' => 'aya');

$soap_client = new SoapClient($soap_url);
$test = $soap_client->Authenticate($sh_param);

echo $test . "\nDone";
?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

See in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php):

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('login'          => "some_name",
                                            'password'       => "some_password"));
```

change `username` to `login` and try the above method

Answer (score 0):

Is `Authenticate()` a SOAP method? In what way is the wsdl secured? What happens if you visit it using the browser?

The SoapClient does not support authentication on the WSDL it's built from, so you'll have to download the WSDL manually (using cURL for example) and create the SoapClient from that file.

Comment: if I go to it from the browser it askes for username and password.

Comment: Hi, how do I know the methods of the Webservice provided? Viewing the xml via browser, how will I know which are the methods? Thanks.

Comment: @oneofakind take a look at the [WSDL wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language). You'll be looking for `<operation name="..." />` elements.

Answer (score 0):

for using on localhost, install WAMP.
Click on wamp tray icon > PHP Services > and enable these options:
**openssl,

php_openssl,

curl;

SOAP,



p.s. possibly, some of free hostings dont have these options**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some **firewall** ? you cannot access to the server ?